# Blocking checkboxes in excel given a condition

Tags: excel, vba

I'm constructing on excel a multiple choice "test" with a limit on the amount of options one can choose but the code I wrote is very buggy, can you help me out? The checkboxes I'm using are the activex found on the developer tab in excel (I know I didn't even attempt to shorten it, I'm very new to this)

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("E20").Value = 1
    If CheckBox1.Value = False Then Range("E20").Value = 0
    If Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value Then
        CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then Range("E21").Value = 1
    If CheckBox2.Value = False Then Range("E21").Value = 0
    If Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value Then
        CheckBox2.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox2.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
    If CheckBox3.Value = True Then Range("E22").Value = 1
    If CheckBox3.Value = False Then Range("E22").Value = 0
    If Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value Then
        CheckBox3.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox3.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()
    If CheckBox4.Value = True Then Range("E23").Value = 1
    If CheckBox4.Value = False Then Range("E23").Value = 0
    If Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value Then
        CheckBox4.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox4.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox5_Click()
    If CheckBox5.Value = True Then Range("E24").Value = 1
    If CheckBox5.Value = False Then Range("E24").Value = 0
    If Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value Then
        CheckBox5.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox5.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()
    If CheckBox6.Value = True Then Range("E25").Value = 1
    If CheckBox6.Value = False Then Range("E25").Value = 0
    If Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value Then
        CheckBox6.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox6.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox7_Click()
    If CheckBox7.Value = True Then Range("E26").Value = 1
    If CheckBox7.Value = False Then Range("E26").Value = 0
    If Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value Then
        CheckBox7.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox7.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox8_Click()
    If CheckBox8.Value = True Then Range("E27").Value = 1
    If CheckBox8.Value = False Then Range("E27").Value = 0
    If Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value Then
        CheckBox8.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox8.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox9_Click()
    If CheckBox9.Value = True Then Range("E28").Value = 1
    If CheckBox9.Value = False Then Range("E28").Value = 0
    If Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value Then
        CheckBox9.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox9.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox10_Click()
    If CheckBox10.Value = True Then Range("E29").Value = 1
    If CheckBox10.Value = False Then Range("E29").Value = 0
    If Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value Then
        CheckBox10.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox10.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox11_Click()
    If CheckBox11.Value = True Then Range("E30").Value = 1
    If CheckBox11.Value = False Then Range("E30").Value = 0
    If Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value Then
        CheckBox11.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox11.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox12_Click()
    If CheckBox12.Value = True Then Range("E31").Value = 1
    If CheckBox12.Value = False Then Range("E31").Value = 0
    If Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value Then
        CheckBox12.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox12.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox_Click()
    ' Refresh the worksheet
    ActiveSheet.RefreshAll
End Sub**your text**
```

I tried running this code and an error: run-time error 1004 came up I don't know what that is or how to solve it. I tried asking chat gpt to debug it no luck.

Comment: `Range(“C19”).Value <= Range(“E13”).Value` you have "smart quotes" here - they need to be changed to regular double-quotes.

Comment: Once you hit the limit of checked boxes, you need to disable all the other non-checked boxes on the sheet: it's not enough to just disable the one that was clicked (in fact you shouldn't disable the *checked* boxes, since your user needs to be able to uncheck one if they want to select a different option).

Comment: Ok thanks!! changed the quotes, about the blocking part tho, is there a way to do that without writing 11 enable statements for each box? I feel like it'd become very cumbersome

Comment: It dawned on me... Wouldn't this make it so that the user cannot change their answers after having reached the limit?

Comment: The trick is they need to uncheck a checked box if they want to change something after they hit the limit - that should trigger all of the unchecked boxes to be re-enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would maybe use something like this (in the worksheet code module):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private colCB As Collection 'for capturing clicks...

'sets up the checkbox click capture...
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set colCB = New Collection
    For Each obj In AllCheckBoxes
        colCB.Add cbWrapper(obj)
    Next obj
End Sub

'return an instance of clsCB
Private Function cbWrapper(obj As Object) As clsCB
    Set cbWrapper = New clsCB
    Set cbWrapper.cb = obj
End Function

'all your checkbox click events just call this
Sub ReviewCheckboxes()
    'Const MAX_CHECKED As Long = 4 'or read this from a cell

    Dim maxChecked A Long
    Dim obj, checkedCB As New Collection, uncheckedCB As New Collection
    
    maxChecked = Me.Range("E13").Value
    For Each obj In AllCheckBoxes 'loop all checkboxes on the sheet
        'add to checked/unchecked collection
        If obj.Value = True Then checkedCB.Add obj
        If obj.Value = False Then uncheckedCB.Add obj
    Next obj
    Debug.Print "Checked:", checkedCB.Count, "Unchecked:", uncheckedCB.Count
    
    For Each obj In uncheckedCB 'process unchecked checkboxes
        'disable unchecked checkboxes if limit is reached
        obj.Enabled = checkedCB.Count < MAX_CHECKED
    Next obj
End Sub

'return a collection of all checkboxes on the worksheet
Private Function AllCheckBoxes() As Collection
    Dim obj As Object
    Set AllCheckBoxes = New Collection
    For Each obj In Me.OLEObjects 'loop all OLE controls on the sheet
        If TypeName(obj.Object) = "CheckBox" Then AllCheckBoxes.Add obj.Object 'is this a checkbox?
    Next obj
End Function
```

Add a new Class module named "clsCB" and in the module's Properties set `Instancing` to `2-PulblicNotCreatable`.  Add this code to the class module:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cb As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub cb_Click()
    Debug.Print "Clicked", cb.Name
    Sheet1.ReviewCheckboxes 'sheet1 is the *codename* for the worksheet
End Sub
```

The class exists so you don't need to write a separate `Click` handler for each checkbox on the sheet. Google "VBA control array" if you want to learn more about this approach.

Comment: How do I make it read from a cell? I used  'Range("E13").Value' but it doesn't work, it wants a fixed value.

Comment: Also, how do I add 'ActiveSheet.RefreshAll' So that I don't have to reinitialize the macro each time?

Comment: Updated to show reading "maxchecked" from a cell.  I'm not sure exactly when you need to re-initialize the macro?  When opening the workbook.

Comment: If you don't want to use the class-based approach then you can just have a click handler for each checkbox which just calls `ReviewCheckboxes`

Comment: Last thing, how can I print the cb value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
' place this above all code, outside of any sub
Dim nCkCount As Integer, bExit As Boolean
Const nMaxCount As Integer = 5  ' your max allowed answers

' change each check box click event to only contain this code
' the reference to the check box and cell would be unique in each click event, ie E20

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    manageClicks CheckBox1, "E29"
End Sub
' example of second check box...

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    manageClicks CheckBox2, "E30"
End Sub

'add this sub to the code
Private Sub manageClicks(CkBx As Object, sCell As String)
    If bExit Then Exit Sub
    If nCkCount >= nMaxCount Then
        If CkBx.Value Then
            bExit = True ' to bypass this code with reset
            CkBx.Value = False
            bExit = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    If CkBx.Value Then
        Range(sCell).Value = 1
        nCkCount = nCkCount + 1
    Else
        Range(sCell).Value = 0
        nCkCount = nCkCount - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't make it work... What am I missing?

Comment: how is it failing, what is the issue, is there an error?  Are you sure you modified each click event as the examples show?

Comment: No errors it just doesn't block other checkboxes

Comment: Review the code, around the max count and the ck count variables.  That is what it is using to block other checkboxes. Something must not be correct in definition there.

Comment: I went with the other one but thanks anyway, I cannot upvote for lack of reputation but still...